# Use mutated vowel as database password in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, encoding, migration, yaml

I have an rails application with an mySQL database and not the permission to change the database password of the user. The problem is that the password contains a mutated vowel like: `asÖs8ss` when I try to run `rake db:migrate` the migration fails with this error:

```
rake aborted!
special characters are not allowed
```

I tried to escape the `Ö` in this ways:

```
\xC3\x96
\u00D6
```

But this doesn't help. I also added `encoding: UTF8` to the database connection and `#encoding: utf-8` to the top of the `database.yml` but nothing helps to solve my problem.

Has anyone an idea how to escape the `Ö` right or to fix this somehow?

**UPDATE** I am using JRuby, if this help?

Comment: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6200 , https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/224 - looks like it *might* be a known bug with YAML

Comment: Is there any workaround? Can't find something working, I tried to `jruby -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -S rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I updated to the newest version of JRuby and run `bundle update` I got it to work. Also you have to make sure, all your files are `utf-8` on my windows machine I had to configure my editor, because default was `ANSI`.

I need to run `db:migrate` with this command:

```
jruby -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -S rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```